# TypeError: List indices must be integers or slices and not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to solve this error for the past two days but I am not able to.

I have to pass the values (which is a list) to the function, but it says:

```
Typerror :list indices must be integers or slices and not str.
```

**here is my code**:

```
def input_execute(board, position, mark):
    board[position] = mark

position = input('enter the position')
input_execute(board_items, position, 'x')
```

**output:**

```
enter the position:5
```

If I enter the position it shows:

```
Typerror :list indices must be integers or slices and not str.
```

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns the input as a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below line returns string

```
position=input('enter the position')
```

now change this line to

```
position=int(input('enter the position : '))
```